# unwanted render using react hooks for state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm a react newbie and im trying to build a simple shopping cart app without the use of class components after finding out about hooks.
In my top level Component App I get a list of items via an imported json, then create a state with useState for the item list and also build a reducer to add or remove items from the cart which has its own state. Each state is being passed into a component, the ItemList together with a function to dispatch the cart state change (SpeiseListe in code) and the Cart.
The ItemList maps the list of items to single Item Components, which have a button which onClick triggers said dispatch and the cart hook state in the top level component gets updated.
Now the problem here is that the whole App rerenders, and so does the ItemList, on every action involving the cart. I would like to update only the Cart Component, but I'm not sure about the right approach.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOE5D.png)

I'm not sure what the solution or a concept to a solution could be. I was thinking of creating the states in ItemList (SpeiseListe) and Cart respectively, but then the Item Component would need to communicate with its parents sibling and that shouldnt be right?

App

```
import React, {useState, useReducer} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import './bootstrap.min.css'

import Speisen from './Speisen'
import Cart from './Cart'

import * as speisen from './speisen.json'


export default function App() {
    const cartHandlerReducer = (cart, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_TO_CART':
                return cart.concat(action.cartItem)
            case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
                return cart.filter(item => item.speise.id !== action.cartItem.speise.id)
            default:
                return cart
        }
    }

    const speisenNumbered = speisen.default.speisen.map((item, i) => ({...item, itemOrder: i + 1}))

    const [cart, dispatch] = useReducer(cartHandlerReducer, [])
    const [speiseListe, setSpeiseListe] = useState(speisenNumbered)

    const cartHandler = (cartItem) => {
        if (cart.find(item => item.speise.id === cartItem.speise.id)) {
            dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART', cartItem})
        } else {
            dispatch({type: 'ADD_TO_CART', cartItem})
        }
    }

    const MainContainer = styled.div.attrs({
        className: 'container'
    })``

    const Row = styled.div.attrs({
        className: 'row'
    })``

    return (
        <MainContainer>
            <Row>
                <Speisen
                    speisen={speiseListe}
                    cartHandler={cartHandler}
                />
                <Cart
                    cart={cart}
                />
            </Row>
        </MainContainer>
    )
}
```

Single Item Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


function Button(props) {
    return (
        <button
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            {props.added ?
                'remove' :
                'add'
            }
        </button>
    )
}


const SpeiseContainer = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'row'
})`
    margin-bottom: 60px;
`

const OrderCol = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'col-1'
})``

const NameCol = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'col'
})``

const PreisCol = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'col-2'
})`
    text-align: right;
`

const ButtonCol = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'col-auto'
})``

export default function Speise (props) {
    const {speise, accomps, cartHandler} = props

    const [currentAccomp, setCurrentAccomp] = useState(accomps && accomps[0].id)

    const changeCurrentAccomp = (event) => setCurrentAccomp(accomps[event.target.value].id)

    const cartItemButton = () => {
        cartHandler({speise, accomps, currentAccomp})
    }

    console.log(currentAccomp)

    return (
        <SpeiseContainer>
            <OrderCol>
                {speise.itemOrder}
            </OrderCol>
            <NameCol>
                {speise.name}
                {currentAccomp && (
                    accomps.length > 1 ? (
                        <select
                            onChange={changeCurrentAccomp}
                        >
                            {accomps.map((accomp, i) => 
                                <option
                                    key={accomp.id}
                                    value={i}
                                >
                                    {accomp.name}
                                </option>
                            )}
                        </select>
                    ):(
                        accomps[0].name
                    )
                )}
            </NameCol>
            <PreisCol>
                {speise.price}
            </PreisCol>
            <ButtonCol>
                <Button onClick={cartItemButton} />
            </ButtonCol>
        </SpeiseContainer>
    )
}
```

I would like to implement a state management using Hooks which makes it possible to add items to the shopping cart without rerendering the item list itself just because both states are being managed in the same component or a different concept of how to do this at all.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If the item list data is not changing at all, you can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) to wrap the ItemList component, which will perform a shallow comparison of the previous and new props and prevent a re-render if they are equal. So inside your `Speisen` component you can simply export it like this:

```
export default React.memo(Speisen);
```

Comment: Thanks! That made things go faster, but it still rerenders. I think there is an underlaying problem in the architecture and the order of the components and I'd love to find out how to go about it in general.
I'd like to be able to filter the item list also later on and am looking for the best practice to realise this shopping app.

Comment: If the ItemList component is giving props to the single items which change, you can try memoizing them as well.

Comment: Ah, I think the issue may be your ```cartHandler``` function.  As an arrow function, it creates a new closure every time it runs, which is technically treated as a new prop for the ItemList.  Try implementing it with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)